# How to compare between three objects in array?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, nsarray

In my card matching game (following the stanford course) I required  to create a `UISwitch` that will change the game mode between matching two cards to three cards matching, now I already have a matching method that looks like this:

```
-(int)match:(NSArray *)cardToMatch {

    int score = 0;

    if (cardToMatch.count == 1) {
        PlayingCards *aCard = [cardToMatch lastObject];

        if ([aCard.suit isEqualToString: self.suit]) {
            score = 1;
        } else if (aCard.rank == self.rank) {
            score = 4;
        }

    }

    return score;
}
```

It's already an array, but I'm only checking between two cards. How can I improve this method to check for three too, or create a separate one?

This is also the method that is checking the cards that have been flipped:

```
-(Card *) cardAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {

    return (index < self.cards.count) ? self.cards[index] : nil;
}


#define FLIP_COST 1
#define MISMATCH_PENALTY 2
#define BONUS 4

-(void) flipCardAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {



    Card *card = [self cardAtIndex:index];

    if (!card.isUnplayable) {

        if (!card.isFaceUp) {

            for (Card *otherCard in self.cards) {

                if (otherCard.isFaceUp && !otherCard.isUnplayable) {

                   int matchScore = [card match:@[otherCard]];

                    if (matchScore) {

                        otherCard.unplayble = YES;
                        card.unplayble = YES;

                        self.notification = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ & %@  match!", card.contents, otherCard.contents];

                        self.score += matchScore * BONUS;
                    } else {
                        otherCard.faceUp = NO;
                        self.score -= MISMATCH_PENALTY;
                        self.notification = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ did not matched to %@", card.contents, otherCard.contents];
                    }
                    break;
                }

            }
            self.score -= FLIP_COST;
        }
        card.faceUp = !card.isFaceUp;

    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but might make you think: Why are you using string comparison to match the suits?  Comparing strings is quite "expensive", so you might want to use an `enum` to represent suits instead as comparing them (integers) is trivial.

Comment: that is a good idea :) thanks. do you maybe have also some solution to my question..? even if I go with your suggestion of using enum, how do I compare 3 objects..? driving me crazy @trojanfoe

Comment: and it's the first time I posted something and no one responded..weird @trojanfoe

Comment: Well in pseudo code this is simply `obj1 == obj2 && obj2 == obj3`.

Comment: yes but when I try to do something similar like 'obj1[0] == obj2[1]' and also I cant do `obj1[0].suit` @trojanfoe

Comment: Rather than having the match method in the card class itself it would be better if you moved it to a controller or a helper class. Then you could follow the method mentioned by @trojanfoe for the comparison.

Comment: Isn't is consider a bad mvc to put model methods in a controller? i'm not saying, i'm really asking? since i'm very new to iOS. @Suhas

Comment: Match is not a model method :) Let's wear our OOP glasses here... In a real life scenario when some people are playing a card game the only responsibility of the card is to display its value, suit (in the case of your app drawing itself). The people playing the game decide weather the cards match or not (which in your case is the game logic). Hence the matching must be done in a controller or a helper class.

Comment: So I don't know why Paul Hegarty put it in the CardMatchingGame model..is this maybe the helper class you are talking about? We created the model that included Card, Deck, PlayingCard(suit,rank), and A PlayingCardDeck. And then we created Another Class Called CardMatchingGame that includes the method flipCardAtIndex which do pretty much all the logic. he put's the match method in the PlayingCard.m which is the model...I don't know I think he knows what he is talking about, maybe i'm confusing something, although I'm sure the match method is in the model PlayingCards.m @Suhas

Comment: I could not make out much from your comment above.. If you could send me a link to your Repo or even a high level design I would be more than happy to take a look.

Comment: Hi Suhas, thanks allot buddy, just created a repo, here's the link https://github.com/NirOhayon/Matchismo.git @Suhas

Comment: Looks like the class CardMatchingGame is handling the game logic in your case. If I were you I'd put the match method in this class. However, if you want to continue with the same design that you have you'll have to introduce one more condition in your flipCardAtIndex method to match the current card with the second one if the 1st card that you are trying to match is a success.

Comment: @Suhas So I was right about Paul Hegarty using the model for this operation? he mentioned the class CardMatchingGame is part of the model..He said that the model is the "what" and a CardMatchingGame is a what...right?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you already know the index of the cards you are trying to match. So if you have three indexes make your matching function return a bool value. Then you can use a nested if to test for the third card. It would look something like this.

```
if([self match:index1 card2:index2]){
    if(self match:index1 card2:index3){
        NSLog(@"You have a match");
    }
}
else NSLog@"No match";
```

Your matching function would look something like:

```
-(BOOL)match:(int)index1 card2:(int)index2{
    //Do your matching here and return if YES or NO accordingly
}
```